# Force BSOD on windows 8.1

Tags: bsod

I have been trying to get windows 8.1 to force into a blue screen, but all of my attempts have failed. I don't really want to go into driver code or anything to do it, but just crash it using some sort of silly loop hole.

I tried creating the CrashOnCtrlScroll registry and it doesn't seem to work, even after restarting my computer. I also tried ending csrss, but microsoft has decided to let the user have no control and denies access at all costs (even after an informative prompt window).

I looked online for a while, but can't find anything on blue screening 8.1. It seems that everything out there is for 8 and below.

Comment: This might be of some help to get BSOD, particularly emphasis on `CTRL + SCROLL LOCK` part : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969028

Comment: Please see my post: ["What to do when CrashOnCtrlScroll doesn't seem to work"](https://superuser.com/questions/1606956/what-to-do-when-crashonctrlscroll-doesnt-seem-to-work).

Comment: Do you remember?: Why did you want to force a BSOD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Notmyfault](http://download.sysinternals.com/files/NotMyFault.zip) , a portable tool created by Microsoft's [Mark Russinovich](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/) for the [Windows Internals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901) book will help you get a BSOD with more than a couple of ways (i.e High IRQ fault, hang IRP, stack trash, deadlock, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Which registry key have you tried? There is different key location for PS2 and USB Keyboard.

USB Registry Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\kbdhid
Add DWORD32, name= CrashOnCtrlScroll, value =0x1

PS2 Registry Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\i8042prt
Add DWORD32, name= CrashOnCtrlScroll, value =0x1

Restart. Hold the RIGHT CTRL key and press SCROLL LOCK twice quicky.